# Create Multi dimension recursive regex with php pairs / array from preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array

I have the following string which I need to be bale to extract the parameters from in order to process the next part of the code. I have manage to do this by doing multiple preg_match_all, but it is not very efficient and/or dynamic.

Example strings (the source might contain multiples):
<==OBJECTSTART==>type=>sqltable,objectid=>4000001,options=>1|5|2<==OBJECTEND==>

<==OBJECTSTART==>type=>sqltable,objectid=>4000002,options=>3|8|5<==OBJECTEND==>

What I have so far I have go to the following for a regex expression:

/<==OBJECTSTART==>((.*?),)(.*?)<==OBJECTEND==>/

This gives me the information before the first comma but I have tried the usual + and * to give me a repeat iteration but no luck.

ideally I am looking for an array of objects that looks like the following

[0]=>

```
[type]=sqltable
[objected]=4000001
[options]=1|5|2
```

[1]=>

```
[type]=sqltable
[objected]=4000002
[options]=3|8|5
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: A solution using regular expressions to parse a string formatted as yours is typically error-prone and not very maintainable. It's often easier to manually parse the string with splits and such. That said, `/([^,=>]+)=>([^,<=>]+)/g` [appears](https://regex101.com/r/mF8sC5/1) to match the keys and corresponding values correctly. If you use it one line at a time, you should be able to build up your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant way of parsing this, but I think it gets the job done:

```
$str = <<<EOS
<==OBJECTSTART==>type=>sqltable,objectid=>4000001,options=>1|5|2<==OBJECTEND==>
<==OBJECTSTART==>type=>sqltable,objectid=>4000002,options=>3|8|5<==OBJECTEND==>
EOS;

foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $str) as $line) {
    $line = preg_replace('/<==OBJECTSTART==>(.*)<==OBJECTEND==>/', '\1', $line);
    $pairs = explode(',', $line);

    $data = array();
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        list ($key, $value) = explode('=>', $pair);
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
    $result[] = $data;
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => sqltable
            [objectid] => 4000001
            [options] => 1|5|2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => sqltable
            [objectid] => 4000002
            [options] => 3|8|5
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks this seem to do the trick and slightly modified for my needs I have created a reusable function that we get the object details process the object and replace the original place holder(s) with the result(s) before outputting the new file.

Answer (score 1):

First extract that is between *<==OBJECTSTART==>* and *<==OBJECTEND==>*

```
  $str= substr($str, strlen("<==OBJECTSTART==>"), -1 * strlen("<==OBJECTEND==>"));
```

Then get all pairs attribute/value

```
  preg_match_all("#([^\=]*)\=>([^\,<]*)#",str,values);
```

Finally, combines the keys and the values in a array

```
  $result= array_combine( $values[1], $values[2] );
```